# Extract specific bean from array of beans obtained using Find in RedBean ORM

Tags: arrays, orm, redbean

Let's say I do this:

```
$results=R::find('markers', ' age = ? ', array($age));
```

Now, `$results` will be an array of beans.

If I want only one bean (instead of an array), and want `$results` to be a bean, I can use `findone` instead of `find`.

If I want to loop through each bean in array and see some property, I could do something like this:

```
foreach($results as $row){
    echo $row->id;
}
```

---

**My question:**

Is there some way to directly reference (say) the 3rd bean in the `$results` array?

Note: The keys in the `$results` array are based on the `id` of each bean. So, even though `$results` may have a size of 3 (or more), doing `$results[2]` will only produce a bean if there's a bean in there with an `id` of 2, and it will not necessarily be the 3rd bean in the array.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do that with PHP's [`array_keys`](http://php.net/manual/function.array-keys.php), or [`array_slice`](http://php.net/manual/function.array-slice.php), or [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/function.array-values.php).

```
<?php

$results = [
    6 => 1,
    66 => 2,
    666 => 3,
];

// Using array_keys
$keys = array_keys($results);
echo $results[$keys[1]]; // 2
echo $results[$keys[2]]; // 3

// Or convert it to an indexed array using array_values
$indexedResults = array_values($results);
echo $indexedResults[1]; // 2

// If you need only one item, you can save a little bit of
// memory by slicing on just this item
$slice = array_slice($results, 1, 1);
echo $slice[0]; // 2

// In PHP 5.4+, you can have them as one-liners
echo $results[array_keys($results)[1]]; // 2
echo array_values($results)[1]; // 2
echo array_slice($results, 1, 1)[0]; // 2
```